# How can I print a double value without .0

Tags: java, android

### TL;DR

My current output is

> Total score is : 0.0
>
> Total score is : 2.4
>
> Total score is : 2.0

Desired output is

> Total score is : 0
>
> Total score is : 2.4
>
> Total score is : 2

My server contains :

[image]

These numbers are doubles, but when I print it on Android doing :

```
System.out.println(mPojo.totalPoints)
```

The output is :

> I/System.out: 0.0
>
> I/System.out: 0.0
>
> I/System.out: 7.5

My question is, is there a way to avoid showing 0.0 and 10.0 and just show decimal in case like 7.5? I mean on Android is showing 0.0 and I'd like to see just 0.

And only for which contains decimals show them.

Comment: You screenshot implies server have 5 entries put you are pinting only 3, none of the 3 prints matches any of the numbers on the screenshot, what?

Comment: Ya @cutiko it's just for a specific user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html):

```
Double value = 5.500;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
System.out.println(format.format(value));  // prints 5.5

Double value = 5.000;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
System.out.println(format.format(value));  // prints 5
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually prefer seeing it the way it appears in your current output, because the format is consistent for all numbers.  That being said, if you really want to strip of the decimal in certain cases, we can try doing that:

```
double input = 10.0d;
String field = String.valueOf(input);
field = field.replaceAll("\\.0+$", "");
System.out.println(field); // should print just 10
```

This approach converts the `double` to a `String`, followed a by a regex replacement of `\.0+$` to remove any all-zero decimal component.

Comment: Yes Tim I agree , but it's like an exam mark, so that's why it's not that cool to see 0.0 instead of 0, or 2.0 instead of 2, you get me?

Comment: What? don't get you

Answer (score 1):

Another funny approach without formatter :

```
double d = 5.0;
long l = (long) d;

if (d - l == 0) {
    System.out.println(l);
} else {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```